# Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following augmented system $\begin{pmatrix}-2-i & 1 & 0\\ -5 & 2-i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

I've tried to solve it but I'm getting the wrong answer and I can't see why. I know I haven't gone about it in the most efficient way but I'm interested to know why I'm wrong.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{-2-i} & 0 \\ -5 & 2-i & 0\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{-2-i} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

So my solution is $\begin{pmatrix}2-i \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want $x+\frac{y}{-2-i}=0$, or (allow me) $x+\frac{-2+i}{5}y=0$, it should be $\operatorname{Span}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2-i}{5}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.